# Chrome update to version 92 throwing exception even after the driver is compatible

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I updated chrome driver to version 92.0.4515.107 and installed .rpm file for chrome version 92. However, upon running the code I see the following exception.
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities

It works fine for lower version, just need to find out what are the capabilities that I can add for version 92.

Answer (score 0):

U can use webdriver manager to Eliminate dependency on drivers

Comment: do you have any links so I can go over ?

Comment: http://www.testautomationpoint.com/webdrivermanager